# VBA Fields.Count returns 2 instead of 3

Tags: vba, ms-word

i try to update the links of my word document with a excel file. i already got this code from the internet

```
Dim fieldCount As Integer
fieldCount = ActiveDocument.Fields.Count
```

but its returning 2 instead of 3.

[My link Settings which shows 3 Items but i only get 2 with the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJaub.png)

How can i count all the items in the link window as i need to update all of them? For me logically the count it return should be 3 not 2.

Is it because the first 2 got the same setting? Same Row so it recognized it as 1 item ?

My full code is changing the first 2 but leave the 3rd as it is.

Tried to +1 the for loop but the item in not recognized then.

Hopefully someone from this Community can help me with that as i really need it :)

Answer (score 0):

That could be because your fields are in different part of document, in different `StoryRanges`. Try with the following loop which goes through all `StoryRanges` and list number of Fields in each of `Range`

```
Sub ListAllFields()

    Dim SR As Range
    For Each SR In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        Debug.Print SR.Fields.Count

    Next SR
End Sub
```

Comment: Its show me the count 2 at index 0 the rest is 0. StoryRanges has the count of 6. So i get the same count back as before which is should be one more